# How to apply linregress in Pandas bygroup

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to apply a scipy.stats.linregress within Pandas ByGroup. I had looked through the documentation but all I could see was how to apply something to a single column like

```
grouped.agg(np.sum)
```

or a function like

```
grouped.agg('D' : lambda x: np.std(x, ddof=1))
```

But how do I apply a linregress which has TWO inputs X and Y?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [`linregress`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html) function, as well as many other scipy/numpy functions, accepts "array-like" X and Y, both Series and DataFrame could qualify.

For example:

```
from scipy.stats import linregress
X = pd.Series(np.arange(10))
Y = pd.Series(np.arange(10))

In [4]: linregress(X, Y)
Out[4]: (1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 4.3749999999999517e-80, 0.0)
```

*In fact, being able to use scipy (and numpy) functions is one of pandas killer features!*

So if you have a DataFrame you can use linregress on its columns (which are Series):

```
linregress(df['col_X'], df['col_Y'])
```

and if using a groupby you can similarly `apply` (to each group):

```
grouped.apply(lambda x: linregress(x['col_X'], x['col_Y']))
```

Comment: Thanks Andy, Yes it can accept it.  The question is how to do it BYGROUP.  For example I have datetime that I have GROUPED into Year and month.  I want to do the linear regression for each of the groups then return the values from the lin regression.   Also I have a DataFram so how can I apply that using two columns in the DF? Thanks Jason

Comment: @user1911866 also, see [this question and its answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410438/how-to-use-pandas-groupby-apply-without-adding-an-extra-index).

Comment: Thanks once more.  How do I exclude NaN values from the linregress calculation?  Is there a way of masking values in the grouped calculations?  Best wishes, Jason.

Comment: @user1911866 This reminds me a lot of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13930367/interpolating-time-series-in-pandas-using-cubic-spline/13931877#13931877), drop the na first then do the calculation. :)

Comment: Ahh. Yes of course.  I was wondering if the 'mask' feature in Pandas would work and was thinking along those lines. Excellent.