# Training Linear Regression Model on 85% of Dataset

Tags: pandas, regression

I'm not exactly sure how to approach this question. The dataset has 8 attributes and one y-value. How would I train a linear regression model on 85% of the dataset?

[image]

Comment: Please do your own homework.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `train_test_split` from `sklearn` as in [sklearn example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) to split the data into training and testing sets e.g. if `X` is data with features and `y` is label then:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.15)
```

And for linear regression you can try using: `linregress` from `scipy` as in  [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48767977/5916727):

Answer (score 0):

Use `ndf = df.sample(frac=0.85)` to get a DataFrame with 85% of your total rows and then use this new DataFrame `ndf` to train your linear regression model.